# Unable to make GIF with Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Please see this code which I have provided to identify the mistake I have done in the code to make a GIF in pillow

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def make_Image(w,h,p_1,p_2):
    
    img = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), (255,255,255))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    draw.rectangle([(p_1,p_2), (p_1+10,p_2+10)], fill = 'red', outline = 'blue')

    return img 

frames = []

x,y = 0,0

for i in range(10):

    new_image = make_Image(200,200,x,y)

    x = x + 20

    y = y + 20

    frames.append(new_image)

frames[0].save('gif_1.gif', format = 'GIF', append_all = frames[1:], save_all = True, duration = 1, loop = 0)
```

Comment: Did you get an error? What happened that shouldn't have happened? What didn't happen that you expected to happen?

Comment: I tried to run your code and it created an image. What's not working there ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `append_images` instead of `append_all`:

```
frames[0].save('gif_1.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], ...
```

(see: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving)